# How to parse uint16_t to int in C?

Tags: c, uint16

I got the data for `uint16_t` and it like `0x2c06`.

For the `0x2c06` , `2c` is the first data and the `06` is the second data.

How do I parse the `0x2c06` and turn the `2c` and the `06` to int?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int lo = number & 0xff; int hi = (number >> 8) & 0xff;`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is your input a string/char* or a `uint16` variable? Also `0x2c` is called a **Byte**

Comment: @DrKoch It put a uint16 variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `char*` and some pointer arithmetic to get this done.

Pseudo-code:

```
uint16_t var = 0x2c06;
unsigned char * temp = &var;

int first = *temp;               //or second, see note
int second = *(temp + 1);       // or first, see note
```

<sub>**Note: You need to take care of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)**</sub>

Comment: The result of this depends on the endianess of the host cpu.

Comment: @trenki yeah, absolutely. That needs to be taken care of. I'll adda line about it in my answer itself.

Comment: If you use `char`, then signedness is implementation defined. Better to use `unsigned char` to avoid problems.

Answer (score -2):

Build a set of case operators cast the uint and just equate it, eg

```
switch(sizeof unsign) 

{

case sizeof (unsigned short int):

  int result = (unsigned short int)unsign;

  break;

default:

  fprintf (stderr, "recast of unit_16  failed.\n");

}
```

Sorry if there's bugs in this, it's just typed into the browser.